# How to measure velocity of hot gas ( temperature range: 100 - 450 ºC)?

Tags: hvac

I want to measure the velocity of hot gas coming out from an incinerator. The temperature can easily shoot upto 400-500ºC. I've checked online for hot-wire anemometers, even they claim to work in the range of 0-50 ºC or 0-70ºC. Moreover they are dearly expensive. Can someone suggest a good and reliable solution?

Comment: Can you add What is the accuracy/tolerance for the results?

Answer (score 1):

Use a pitot tube made of a suitable metal and measure the profile across the pipe.

Did a lab experiment like this years ago to measure the flow profile before and after an axial flow fan.